# Use of "while" vs "as"

Tags: prepositions

What does the word "as" describe in the following sentence?

> *As I was about to get out of bed, I heard a noise coming from the kitchen downstairs.*

- Does "as" imply simultaneous short actions?
- Is "as" just background information?
- Can "while" be used instead?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"While" will indicate an action in progress, but "as", as you use it here, is simply a marker of the time when you were getting up (just like @Mowzer said), hence it's the right word to use, in my opinion.

Comment: I agree with your analysis of the use of "while." In fact, you would have to write something like "While I was getting out of bed,..." which is a different verb tense.

Comment: @MaulikV I guess, when is not appropriate here too, right?

Comment: I am new here, so thank you all, for your encouraging comments! Glad I could help.

Comment: @D.B no, it's not. It's appropriate but does not substitute 'As'

Comment: @MaulikV Interesting, so what it would mean if we substituted 'when' with 'as'?

Comment: 'when' is more about 'timing' and 'as' about 'the event' ;)

Answer (score 1):

You need the word "as" in this sentence because it informs the reader that everything following the clause happened **contemporaneously with** (i.e., **at the same time as**) the events inside the clause (i.e., when the writer was "about to get out of bed.")

*Native speaker*