# what is the subtle difference between as and when

Tags: as

I often raked my brain when I encountered subtle usage of as and when, making it hard to write them accurately.

Let me write some example sentences that are quite confusing to me containing as and when, both used in a temporal reference.

> 1. He dropped a glass of wine **when** his eyes met hers at a party.
> 2. He surveyed the crowd at the club for any signs of suspicious moves **as** a rock 'n roll blared out from giant loudspeakers at the corner.

In my gut feelings, when in sentence 1 is replaceable with as, without change in meaning. But sentence 2 is a bit different. When *as* is supplanted with *when*, it feels like a bit different to me, it's hard to say why, though.  Is there anyone that can draw a clear-cut disction between as and when in these sentences?

Finally, one more question.

Whar's the differences in the following?

> 1. I was writing a draft novel **when** a doorbell rang out.
> 2. A doorbell rang out **when** I was writing a draft novel.
> 3. **When** I was writing a draft novel, a doorbell rang out.

Some say the difference between 1 and 2 is where to put emphasis on.  Is it right?  (By the way, Asians  usually took the 3 when they speak in their mother tongue while English natives tend to speak 1 or 2, which is quite linguistically intriguing.)

I would really appreciate it if differences between sentences 1 and 2, and ones between 2 and 3 are fully explained respectively.

Comment: "Rock 'n' roll" is a mass noun. You wouldn't use an indefinite article with it (though you *could* use the definite article).

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. I need to pay more attention to countable/uncountable nouns.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [As, when or while?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/69514/as-when-or-while) Also [Use of “while” vs “as”](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/65959/use-of-while-vs-as), [The difference between “as” “when” and “while”](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/83971/the-difference-between-as-when-and-while), and doubtless several others.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you say, the differences between "when" and "as" can be subtle, but nevertheless distinct.  "When" implies a *particular moment in time*, and "as" implies *concurrent action* -- which is to say, a *distinct* moment in time vs. a *period* of time.

> **When** she walked into the room, they all stood up and applauded.

= *At the moment* she entered the room, they applauded.

> **As** she walked into the room, they all stood up and applauded.

= *While* she was *entering* the room, they applauded.

In many cases this distinction is trivial.  It only takes a moment to enter a room, so both sentences imply much the same thing.  The difference is in the image of what *she* is doing at the time.  "When" suggests she entered, stopped, and they applauded.  "As" suggests she was still *walking* as they started *applauding*.

Either can imply causality:

> **When/As** he turned his head to watch her go by, he walked into a tree.

As Tupelo Thistlehead mentioned, if an action is *continuous* or *ongoing* then use "as":

> **As** the kids were playing in the yard, their mother watched them from the kitchen.

If it's a particular action at a specific moment in time, use "when":

> **When** one of the children fell down and bruised her knee, the mother rushed to comfort her

The order of the words is really not all that significant.  Yes, you can change the order to add emphasis, or so the words *flow* better, but there's not much difference between these:

> **As** she was walking she was singing.
>   She was walking **as** she was singing.
>
> **When** the music played, they danced.
>   They danced **when** the music played.

"When" does define the *order* of events, so the following is different.  It implies the music played *because* they danced, and not (as is typical) the other way around:

> **When** they danced, the music played.

Lastly, a direct translation of some Asian grammar structures can be perfectly natural English, although you might have to use something other than "when".

> **At the moment** I started writing my novel, the doorbell rang.

Comment: Thank Andrew so much. Your detailed comment featuring easy-to-understandable examples really hit the spot. It really quenched my thirst for informed distinction on as and when usages.

Comment: @commander  you're welcome, but please check out the duplicate questions FumbleFingers linked in his comment.  This particular question comes up a lot.  Also in the future you may want to wait a day or two before selecting the "correct" answer, since someone might write a better one.

Comment: your advice is a lot helpful to me as a newcomer to this platform. I will pore over the links by FumbleFingers yet again to find out whether my question is redundant and has been already solved in other posts. And I will be more patient before clicking a tick to label a correct answer.

Answer (score -1):

In sentence 1, the word "when" helps to establish causality. Implied is the idea that her beauty (or something) so overwhelmed or startled the writer that he was unable to maintain the grip on his glass. Yes, you could replace "when" with "as", but to my ear, the sense of causality is not as strong.

In sentence 2, "as" implies no causality, only actions proceeding simultaneously. If you were to modify the sentence thus:

> As (or while) he surveyed the crowd at the club for any signs of suspicious moves when a rock 'n roll blared out from giant loudspeakers at the corner.

You'd be saying that the "blaring" started up (perhaps abruptly) while the "surveying" was going on.

Regarding the other question (first, the question police are going to ding you for asking two questions..) Again, "as" implies on-going or "imperfect" activity, so I'd be inclined to replace "when" with "as" or "while". The words "rang out" imply a jarring interruption, which is better set up by putting the "writing" clause first. If you don't mean to imply the jarring interruption then,

```
While I was writing a novel, the doorbell rang.
```

is just fine.

Comment: And you "racked" your brain. Raking means that you stroked it with a garden implement. :-)

Comment: I see no such causality occasioned by *when*.

Comment: "When" can certainly *imply* causality but it isn't inherent to the term.  Rather it means "at the moment of "  and readers can draw their own conclusions, "At the moment his eyes met hers, he dropped his glass".  In fact I would say in this case it might actually *contradict* the idea of causality, since there are better ways to say that, "His eyes met hers and his glass dropped from his suddenly nerveless fingers" etc.

Comment: @Robusto: I'll throw my two penn'orth in, ***as*** I think it's relevant. If I'd used ***when*** there, it would have been a "temporal" reference to some possible future time when I [might] think my contribution is relevant. But obviously my actual choice of ***as*** means ***because*** in that particular context (implying "causality"). It seems to me ***when*** can at most *indirectly* imply causality through the semantics of ***when = at the same time as, or directly following*** (which also applies to ***as*** in that sense). But in my usage, ***as*** *directly* implies "cause, reason".

Comment: @FumbleFingers: To say that something that directly follows something else is caused by it is to be guilty of one of the commonest logical fallacies in the book: [*post hoc ergo propter hoc*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post_hoc_ergo_propter_hoc).

Comment: Tupelo Thistlehead, thanks for your sharp eye and kindly detailed feedback.  Although Robusto doesn't see implied causality in the conjuction"when", Andrew and FumbleFingers suggest "when" could be contextually implied for causality.  Of course,  as Robusto points out, the time sequence doesn't mean there is a definte causal relationship between the events.     After reading comments, I'd might have a conclusion that when, as used in a temporal context, could imply indirect causality while as is more concerned with simultaneousness and coincidence of events mentioned.  Thanks for all.

Comment: @Robusto: I never claimed otherwise. But obviously in these days of "big data" it's a *serious* political hot potato. For example, we know black guys in the US/UK get hassled by police more than whites - and it's simply not credible that's just a "statistical fluke", so there's bound to be some reason for the correlation. Maybe a preexisting pattern of discrimination actually *promotes* subsequent law-breaking that some then claim is a "cause" when it could more accurately be described as a "consequence". Big data will soon shed much light on such matters, I feel.

Comment: Ah, plus 'when' has a connotation of brief interruption as well. By the way,  as far as I know, establishing causality between two events requires a meeting of three conditions: one event should precedes the other; a reasonable account on the two' relationship; the absence of a third factor that could influence the two events.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: I'm not sure what you meant to suggest  by your big-data example, but it has nothing to do with the spurious notion that *when* implies causality.

Comment: @Robusto: Big data means we know know of far more ***correlations*** than we did just a few decades/years (months/weeks?!) ago. When we see X and Y apparently correlated graphically, we tend to assume one causes the other. And speaking for myself, I have no problem understanding the syntactic role of ***when*** in the preceding sentence as implying causality. Take the example *When you rattle people's cages, they might bite back*. There, ***when = if***, which nets down to *If X [then] Y* (implying *X causes Y*).

Comment: @FumbleFingers: I understand the role of data with respect to correlations. What I'm saying is that's irrelevant to the point being made here.

Comment: @Robusto: Sorry, I think I misunderstood your first comment. Are you saying you don't think ***when*** implies "causality" *specifically* in OP's first context? Or *in general?* I think pragmatically we can assume he dropped the glass *because* his eyes met hers (by implication, it wouldn't have happened otherwise). But if earlier text had primed us that he often dropped things (because of arthritic hands, say), the writer could in principle force the "coincidentally close in time" interpretation by using ***just when***.

Comment: "When his eyes met hers he dropped his glass" implies no literal causality. It may lead one to infer that him seeing her was the reason he dropped the glass, but that is not explicit.

Comment: Well, I see you've all been beating a dead horse without any help from me, but let me add another whack. I assumed - from the context - that the writer *wanted* to imply causality, which is  why I said that "when" HELPS in that regard, at least to my ear. I certainly did not mean to endorse logical fallacies, let alone police misconduct!